# File Upload to SharePoint using RPC (Vbscript)

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript, rpc

I'm currently using the following VB script and frontpage RPC calls to upload documents and their perspective metadata values, which are configured in the script, to a Sharepoint 2007 and 2010 site. However, files with extension *.xlsx or *.docx do not get their metadata uploaded using this script.

After researching various websites, it seems to be a problem with the way the _vti_aut/author.dll handles the new open office format in WSS 3.0. Some suggestions are to use the SetDocsMetaInfo method after a file has been uploaded to the SharePoint site.

The problem is, I don't understand how to use this Method with this script. When I try to use it, I am able to get the *.xlsx or *.docx file uploaded with the correct metadata but then the file gets corrupted.

Some websites that I have researched have suggested it might be the way the file is encoded but I'm not that familar enough with encoding to accurately troubleshoot it.

Can someone provide some examples on how to use this method (SetDocsMetaInfo) with the below script or provide a solution to this problem using this script?

This original script was retrieved from this website:

```
UploadFile "C:\Test\Work\temp\defer\testDoc_083011.xlsx", _     
"http://sharepoint.domainname.com/Sites/SITE1", _     
"TestImport/folder1/testDoc_083011.xlsx_083011.xlsx", _     
"Test", _     
"Test checkin comment", _     
"", "" 

MsgBox "Done" 

Function StringToByteArray(str)    

    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")    
    stream.Open    
    stream.Type = 2 ''adTypeText    
    stream.Charset = "ascii"    
    stream.WriteText str    
    stream.Position = 0    
    stream.Type = 1 ''adTypeBinary    
    StringToByteArray = stream.Read()    
    stream.Close 

End Function  

Sub UploadFile(sourcePath, siteUrl, docName, title, checkincomment, userName, password)  

    strHeader = "method=put+document%3a12.0.4518.1016" + _       
    "&service_name=%2f" + _       
    "&document=[document_name=" + Escape(docName) + _       
    ";meta_info=[vti_title%3bSW%7c" + Escape(title) + ";Business Unit%3bSW%7c" + Escape("Business Unit")+ "]]" + _       
    "&put_option=overwrite,createdir,migrationsemantics" + _       
    "&comment=" + _       
    "&keep%5fchecked%5fout=false" + vbLf 

    bytearray = StringToByteArray(strHeader)    

    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")    
    stream.Open    
    stream.Type = 1 ''adTypeBinary    
    stream.Write byteArray 

    Set stream2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")    
    stream2.Open    
    stream2.Type = 1 ''adTypeBinary    
    stream2.LoadFromFile sourcePath    
    stream2.CopyTo stream, -1    
    stream.Position = 0     

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")    
    xmlHttp.open "POST", siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll", false, userName, password    
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"    
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Vermeer-Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"    
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "FrontPage"    
    xmlHttp.send stream     

    If xmlHttp.status = 200 Then         
        If Instr(xmlHttp.responseText, "successfully") = 0 Then            
            MsgBox "ERROR: " & vbCrLf & xmlHttp.responseText                
        Else            

            ''Checkin            
            strHeader = "method=checkin+document%3a12.0.4518.1016" + _              
            "&service_name=%2f" + _              
            "&document_name=" & Escape(docName) + _              
            "&comment=" + Escape(checkincomment) + _              
            "&keep%5fchecked%5fout=false" + vbLf      

            Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")           
            xmlHttp.open "POST", siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll", false, userName, password           
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"           
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Vermeer-Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"           
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "FrontPage"           
            xmlHttp.send strHeader           
        End If     
    End If     

      If xmlHttp.status / 100 <> 2 Then       
        MsgBox "ERROR: status = " & xmlHttp.status & vbCrLf & xmlHttp.responseText    
      End If  
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I had just this problem and found that using an apparently deprecated version of the routine worked as per code below Set document meta-info worked OK:

```
Public Sub SetSPMetaData(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal sDocName As String, ByVal sTitle As    String, _
                     Optional ByVal OriginalPath As String, Optional ByVal OriginalName As String, _
                     Optional ByVal ModDate As Date, Optional ByVal FileID As Long)

Dim strHeader As String
Dim byteArray() As Byte
Dim stream As New ADODB.stream
Dim stream2 As New ADODB.stream
Dim xmlHTTP As New MSXML2.xmlHTTP
Dim sTempFile As String
Dim UserName As String
Dim Password As String


On Error GoTo SetSPMetaData_Error

'Method = setDocsMetaInfo: server_extension_version
'&service_name=/[&listHiddenDocs=(true|false)]
'&listLinkInfo=(true|false)&url_list=list_of_urls
'&metaInfoList=(list_of_meta_info)[&errorFlags=(KeepGoing|StopOnFirst)]


'POST /site_url/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll HTTP/1.0
'.
'.
'.
'method=set+docs+meta+info:6.0.n.nnnn
'&service_name=/
'&url_list=[List_Name/File_Name]
'&metaInfoList=[[vti_title;SR|Web+Settingt;SW|fp40]]true
'&listLinkInfo=true

If OriginalPath = "" And OriginalName = "" Then
    strHeader = "method=set+document+meta-info:6.0.n.nnnn" + _
                "&service_name=/&document_name=" & sDocName & _
                "&meta_info=[vti_title;SR|" & Replace(Escape(sTitle), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & "]"
Else

    If OriginalName = "" Then
        If CLng(ModDate) = 0 Then

            strHeader = "method=set+document+meta-info:6.0.n.nnnn" + _
                        "&service_name=/&document_name=" & sDocName & _
                        "&meta_info=[vti_title;SR|" & Replace(Escape(sTitle), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & _
                        ";Original Path;SR|" & Replace(Escape(OriginalPath), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & "]"


        Else

            strHeader = "method=set+document+meta-info:6.0.n.nnnn" + _
                        "&service_name=/&document_name=" & sDocName & _
                        "&meta_info=[vti_title;SR|" & Replace(Escape(sTitle), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & _
                        ";Original Modified|" & Format(ModDate, "DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss") & _
                        ";Original Path;SR|" & Replace(Escape(OriginalPath), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & "]"

        End If

    Else

        If CLng(ModDate) = 0 Then
            strHeader = "method=set+document+meta-info:6.0.n.nnnn" + _
                        "&service_name=/&document_name=" & sDocName & _
                        "&meta_info=[vti_title;SR|" & Replace(Escape(sTitle), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & _
                        ";Original Name;SR|" & Replace(Escape(OriginalName), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & _
                        ";Original Path;SR|" & Replace(Escape(OriginalPath), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & "]"
        Else

            strHeader = "method=set+document+meta-info:6.0.n.nnnn" + _
                        "&service_name=/&document_name=" & sDocName & _
                        "&meta_info=[vti_title;SR|" & Replace(Escape(sTitle), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & _
                        ";Original Name;SR|" & Replace(Escape(OriginalName), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & _
                        ";Original Modified;TW|" & Format(ModDate, "DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss") & _
                        ";Original Path;SR|" & Replace(Escape(OriginalPath), "%5C", "%5C%5C") & "]"

        End If
    End If
End If

byteArray = StringToByteArray(strHeader)

'Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

If gConfig.GetConfig("frmHTTPAuthentication") = 2 Then
    If gConfig.GetConfig("txtUserPassword") <> "" Then Password = gConfig.GetConfigDecrypt("txtUserPassword")
    If gConfig.GetConfig("txtUserName") <> "" Then UserName = gConfig.GetConfigDecrypt("txtUserName")
End If

stream.Open
stream.Type = 1    ''adTypeBinary
stream.Write byteArray


stream.Position = 0
'stream.SaveToFile "C:\StreamContent.txt"

xmlHTTP.Open "POST", sURL + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll", False, UserName, Password
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-Vermeer-Content-Type", "application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "FrontPage"
xmlHTTP.send stream

If xmlHTTP.Status = 200 Then

    If InStr(xmlHTTP.responseText, "osstatus=0") <> 0 Then
        '230               MsgBox "Error - " & cleanup_html(xmlHTTP.responseText)
        Call LogErrorFilFol(GetFileFromPath(sURL), GetFolderFromPath(sURL), _
                            "SetSPMetaData - osstatus = 0 - " & cleanup_html(xmlHTTP.responseText), FileID)
    End If
    '260           Debug.Print xmlHTTP.responseText

Else

    Call LogErrorFilFol(GetFileFromPath(sURL), GetFolderFromPath(sURL), "SetSPMetaData - Status = " & xmlHTTP.Status, FileID)

End If
```